# intent classification- openai/ langchain

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, conversational-ai

What are the ways that we can do intent classification in a conversation. If we have used conversational chain is there anyway we can do that.

I need to identify the users intention to update or insert operation. But I dont know which line exactly say the intention. Any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This is my code using AzureOpenAI and LangChain to do the intent classification. Btw, this is zero-shot prompting. It is better for you to have examples to feed in the prompt to make the classification more promissing.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import openai
from langchain.llms.huggingface_hub import HuggingFaceHub
from langchain.llms.openai import OpenAI, AzureOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.chains import LLMChain

# Load the OpenAI API key from the .env file
def load_openai_credentials():
    load_dotenv()
    openai.api_type = os.environ["OPENAI_API_TYPE"]
    openai.api_key = os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]
    openai.api_base = os.environ["OPENAI_API_BASE"]
    openai.api_version = os.environ["OPENAI_API_VERSION"]

# Instartiate AzureOpenAI object 
def create_llm():
    llm = AzureOpenAI(
        deployment_name="text-davinci-003",
        model_name="text-davinci-003",
        temperature=0.3,
        max_tokens=40,
        # frequency_penalty=0, # Default is 0
        presence_penalty=0.88, # Default is 0
    )
    return llm

# Create prompt template
def create_prompt(llm):
    prompt = """
    Please act as a robust and well-trained intent classifier that can identify the most likely PRECISE, SHORT and GENERIC intent behind a user's query WITHOUT USING the proper and common noun subject from the user's query.

    The identified intent must be less than six words.

    User's query: {question}

    Intent:
    """
    return PromptTemplate(template=prompt, input_variables=['question'])

def main():

    # ============================================= Azure OpenAI =============================================

    # Load the OpenAI API key from the .env file
    load_openai_credentials()

    # Create LLM
    llm = create_llm()

    # Create prompt template
    prompt_template = create_prompt(llm)

    # Create LLMChain
    llm_chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt_template)

    # ============================================= Load Query Data from CSV =============================================

    # Load the Excel workbook
    df = pd.read_excel('J.AI Search & Chat Latest PBI_OpenAI.xlsx')

    # Convert the column 'Latest Search Merge New[SearchString]' as a list
    lst_of_str = df['Latest Search Merge New[SearchString]'].tolist()
    # lst_of_str = ["What is DD&I?", "What is Transformers?", "PD&T", "Who is the head of Enterprise Data Hub in Petronas Digital Pte. Ltd."]

    # Convert list_of_str variable to a list of dictionaries
    # Format: questions = [{'question': "1st str in the list"}, {'question': "2nd str in the list"}, ...]
    questions = [{'question': str(s)} for s in lst_of_str]

    # Get intents from LLMChain
    intents = llm_chain.generate(questions)
    # print(f'{intents.dict().get("generations")}\n')

    # Retrieve the intents and save it as a list
    intents_lst = [intent[0].get('text').replace('\n', ' ').strip() for intent in intents.dict().get("generations")]

    for intent in intents.dict().get("generations"):
        print(intent[0].get('text').replace('\n', ' ').strip())
    
    # Convert the list to a series
    intents_series = pd.Series(intents_lst)

    # Add the Series to the DataFrame
    df = df.assign(**{'Intent': intents_series})

    # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    df.to_excel('OpenAI Intent.csv', index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```